# Error TS2604: JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a package that contains common components that we created on the company I work for, and we want available for all projects. We use TypeScript, and I moved the code to a new project and I am able to publish to npm and add the package in the dependencies section of one of my projects. However, when I try to use it I get a compile error saying

`error TS2604: JSX element type 'Loader' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

my code (simplified) looks like this:

```js
import Loader from "my-common-components";
export class Contact extends React.Component<any, any> {
.
.
.
    public render() {
        this.state.loading) && <Loader />
        <div>Hello World</div>
    }
}
```

The linter indicates that the error is on the `<Loader />` part, however the code of this component (`Contact`) didn't change, I just moved `Loader` away from the project and into a separate package (`my-common-components`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out that the error was that when moving to the separate package, I added the component to an index file that reexported the component. But by doing so, I made it cease to be a *default* export. Kind of obvios in hindsight. So the fix was to wrap the name of the component name in curly braces so to import the actual named component, like this:

`import { Loader }from "my-common-components";`

and that's it. I hope I saved someone from making the same mistake, as when searching I found lots of places describing the same error but caused by different roots, like the Typescript version and wrong `required` instructions.