# Render prop as string or component with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that conditionally renders/returns a string or a dynamic component depending on what type the prop is:

```
const renderValue = (value: string | React.ReactNode) => {
  if (React.isValidElement(value)) {
    const Component = value
    return <Component />
  }
  return value
}
```

However, with the above code I get the following message from Typescript:

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

I have read [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815633/what-does-the-error-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452966/typescript-3-jsx-element-type-component-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-s) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964924/typescript-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080760/error-ts2604-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatu) [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675920/jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures) on SO, but still haven't concluded an answer.

Comment: What happens if you remove 'string' from type?

Comment: You can use `return <value />`

Comment: @kinduser Nothing happens.

Comment: @RaminRezazadeh A component has to be capitalized.

Comment: What you have looks like a functional component, would it be alright to use your function as a functional component? `const RenderValue`?

Answer (score 1):

`<Component />` is JSX notation and it's basically telling React to render this component. That's only possible in `React Component` which has to return JSX code. To solve the problem you could just check if argument is valid element and then render it conditionally in desired `React Component`

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
   value: string | React.ReactNode
}

const SomeComponent:React.FC<Props> = ({value}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Hello World</span>
      {React.isValidElement(value) ? <Component/> : value}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just edited the answer, if value is not valid element just render string